# MarkLogic Scheduler, Can we pass parameters to the scheduled module?

Tags: marklogic

Is there a way to pass request parameters to the scheduled task module in MarkLogic. In the documentation they have mention we cannot give ? to pass request parameters in task path while creating scheduler. Is there a alternate way to do this. Since we could not do this we are dynamically creating modules and giving them as task path. If we could pass the parameters then we dont have to create the module files for task path.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try the following approach instead:

1. Store the user's inputs (the additional information from the user) as an XML/JSON document in your content database. This document will include the time at which you want the task to run. Let's say these documents are in the "task-input" collection
2. Create a scheduled task as you're currently doing, but it will run the same module in all cases.
3. Rework that module to query for documents in the "task-input" collection with a time parameter within one minute of the current time. For each document that's returned, execute some code that processes the inputs with the document.

Now you have a more data-driven way of implementing this that only needs one module + N scheduled tasks + N task-input documents. No need to pass parameters to the module (there's not a way to do that), you instead find those parameters via a simple query.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please clarify a bit more - and perhaps a more complete answer could be created.

For "request parameters", one would normally think of http requests. That's why this is confusing to me.

Maybe this is enough for you:
For us, various programs, web pages, etc create XML configuration files. We then use scheduled tasks for the programming logic. These various tasks are not set with any parameters. They just know to read certain types of config files and react appropriately.

Comment: thanks for the response, yes for certain task we also use xml  config files for scheduled task. But here in my situation we are using admin apis to create schedule while capturing the schedule details from the user, we are also capturing additional information from the user for the schedule. Hence we would like to pass these additional parameters to the scheduled module on its invocation. This is what we are trying to achieve. We could add these user inputs to config files as well, but how can we differentiate between different task and fetch the correct config info.

Comment: Well, the task scheduler only runs a main module, so I do not know of any way to give it more information anyway.  Having a main module that runs every xx time and and has logic built in to handle tasks as defined in XML config files (and then probably spawning theses tasks from the main control task) seems like a good approach (as long as you'r not going to flood the task queue). the params in this xml config could even include whatever params you need to pass as well as things like module, namespace and function, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @rjrudin is a good approach. You can also alter that approach a little to make it look for task files in the content database. Each task file contains one task path (and any extra info you like to pass through). Spawn a task for each task file. You can look at the task files as a custom queue in which the task server provides the worker threads.

Alternatively you could also just spawn a process directly at the point where you determine the task path. You can then provide all external variables you need, and push it to the built-in task server queue.

HTH!